# How to get live connection status of devices in ThingsBoard?

Tags: thingsboard

I recently started working with thingsboard in context of my bachelor-thesis. Right know I am trying out different functionalities in order to check which requirements thingsboard already satisfies and which have to be implemented by me.

Within that process I am stuck at the requirement that thingsboard dashboard should give live information about the connectivity status of a registered device (connected, disconnected, active, inactive).

To solve that I've tried out editing the rule chain used by the device profile assigned to the device of interest. Specifically I worked with the `message type switch` and tried out various action nodes connected to it via ConnectEvent, DisconnectEvent, ActiveEvent and InactiveEvent. What I would like to have is the connectivity status of the device to be stored in an `SERVER_SCOPE` attribute and then being displayed in the entity widget. All I've achieved is to generate an alarm when disconnected and cleared when (re)connected. I know there is a server side attribute called `active` that changes `true` immediately when device connects but it only turns `false` after the `inactivityTimeout` expired.

I also checked the [ThingsBoard Device Connectivity Status](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/device-connectivity-status/) page, the [Create Alarm when the Device is offline](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/create-inactivity-alarm/) guide and took long researches but couldn't get it to work.

Do you guys have any solutions or tips for me?

Kind regard.

Comment: What determines the state of the device? By that I mean, what does connectivity state mean to you? Posted in the last x minutes/seconds? In my solution, I represent the state of a device via its `lastActivityTime` server attribute which is appropriate for me but may not be for you.

Comment: I would like to distinguish between the states `connected` (based on `lastConnectTime` or `ConnectEvent`), `disconnected` (based on `lastDisconnectTime` or `DisconnectEvent`), and `lastActivityTime` would be neet to know too. The variables the states are based on are easy to show but I would like to have it as a binary connected variable or some string saying "connected"/"disconnected".

Comment: In your rule chain, can you put a (blue) Transform - Script node and configure it with some logic? Say, "on connect event -> `connected = true`" and then save that via the Save Attributes node?

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much. That did the trick! I'll post an answer so anyone else can apply the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @JacksonB I managed to solve my problem.

What did I do?

1. Create a blue Transform-script node.
2. Change message type to `POST_ATTRIBUTES_REQUEST` and add desired attributes.
   Here's my code for that:

   var newType = "POST_ATTRIBUTES_REQUEST"

   msg.connectivity = "connected"

   return {msg: msg, metadata: metadata, msgType: newType};
3. Than just connect this to an post attribute node in the rule chain like shown in the image.
   [Link to screenshot of rule chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oUEt.png)

No I am able to instantly see if a device is connected or disconnected by displaying the value of that attribute on my dashboard.